# google maps v2 API key on different computers

Tags: android, google-maps, api-key

i am using google maps v2 to display a map on my android app. the SHA1 fingerprint and API key is unique to each computer so i do i make sure my app can work on all computers, even when developing the application. i need to run my application on other laptop or pc. is there a way to do that?

EDIT: i am following this tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IYhJp-jqJyM and is clicking export sign application package but it has the error

[image: error message]

i cannot copy and paste so i post a screenshot here

in my strings

```
    <string name="app_name">StudentHealthApp</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="displayMap">Google Map Display</string>
<string name="StartMove">Start Moving</string>
<string name="Pause">Pause</string>
<string name="Resume">Resume</string>
<string name="Stop">Get Distance</string>
<string name="DistanceText">Display Text</string>
<string name="title_activity_finish">FinishActivity</string>
```

all the name="text" has error. 
also, since this tutorial is 2011 does it still work for google maps api v2? if i need to compile my work with my team work. so i have to do it again?

Answer (score 4):

You can synchronize your signing keys, so that you use just a couple of SHA1 fingerprints (debug and production). You can just copy the keystores between the machines, though note that I have not tried copying keystores from Windows <-> OS X/Linux, so I have no idea if there are line-ending issues that might be a problem there.

Or, with Maps V2, you can associate multiple SHA1 fingerprint+package name pairs with a single Maps V2 API key. Normally, you only need to do that for a debug and a production signing key, but if you want to use N independent debug keys, that should work as well.

Comment: do you know where can i find information on how to do this? i search everywhere but most is just explaining how to obtain key for a system, which I've already done

Comment: @Myst: Keystores are just files. Copy them like any other file. Again, I don't know if they are in text or binary form, and hence I do not know if Windows line-ending differences will play in here.